# OS Command Injection from Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net, code-injection, process.start, veracode

My application is using `Process.Start` for opening another application to run. VeraCode [a security software scanning tool] reported this command as [OS Command Injection Vulnerable](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html). I would like to get some comment. I have found a lot of information on the web regarding to filter the input or to constraint the program name; however, I am curious to see if there's any other alternatives of using `Process.Start`?

Edit:
Thanks for the comment, here is one of the sample, and yes, it is getting input from users:

```
public static void Run(string fileName, string arguments, bool waitForExit)
{
    Process p = Process.Start(fileName, arguments);

    if (waitForExit)
        p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is or how your program is calling Process.Start?

Comment: Are you passing user-input to Process.Start?

Comment: "it is reported".  What is reporting?

Comment: I edited my question. I think I am looking for a more proactive way of getting rid of the Command injection, rather than just protect my application by white list + black list , or filter the inputs. I can think of if it is opening url, I can enforce it as http / https, but not sure about executing a program.

Comment: The vulnerability is that the user can execute an arbitrary program. That appears to be the intended function of your code - is it?

Comment: I assume (and hope) this is only reported because either of these parameters can be manipulated by user input. You should check the calls of this method and whether and how the parameters are affected by user input.

Comment: I understand the vulnerability, but I would like to know what input I should be definitely filtered to minimize the risk?

Answer (score 3):

This is a command injection vulnerability because you have not filtered out the users input from the function and directly appended to the process.start()
Due to this, the tool has marked it as a vulnerability.

To avoid this issue you should use regex method to filter out the bad characters and depending on what that function is going to do when it gets run.

for eg. you function is created only to check from this path c:/users/docs.txt
then that function should not get executed for c:/admin/docs.txt.

This is how you need to validate before sending the user data directly into the process.

For more information refer this awesome link : https://dotnet-security-guard.github.io/SG0001.htm

or
https://www.veracode.com/security/dotnet/cwe-78

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer, but I too have run into this problem, and despite my best Regex, Veracode is still complaining. 

Answer (score 2):

The [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) class is nothing else then a Managed wrapper class the the Native [Create Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) and its Variations like [Create Process As User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) .

- [Process MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Process
  SourceCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs)

I don't think that there is another way to start a process than this, because every other solution would also call the WinAPI function. ( because this function (or its overloads and Variations) is  the only way to start a process in Windows).

Personally, I have not heard anything about a problem with `Process.Start` please clarify the problem

regards

Comment: `The Process class is nothing else then a Managed wrapper class the the Native CreateProcess and its Variations. ` I've used `process` more than a million times and never knew that. +1

Comment: `please clarify then problem.` use comments to ask questions to OP.

Comment: hehe yea a Funny fact a lot of classes in .net are just wrapper for native Win32 Functions.

Just take a look into the Process class:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs

Comment: @L.B I tired to awsner the Op's question as best i could. This "phase" is just to remind the op that if the need an other answer he should "reconsider" this question :-)

Comment: It calls `ShellExecuteEx` instead if UseShellExecute is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. You need to set the **UseShellExecute** property to false. Then Veracode will not consider it a vulnerability.

```
using (WinProcess myProcess = new WinProcess())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    myProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: Likely more a bug with the Veracode scanner than making the code more secure. Setting `UseShellExecute` to `false` only directs the code to not use the graphical shell. You will still want to make sure `FileName` or `Arguments` is not a value that can be user controlled and/or use an approve list.

Comment: I tried this using Veracode, and it did not fix my issue.